# Не работает цикл в одном из unit-ов распознавателя цепочки Бэкуса-Наура

Tags: pascal

Задали написать распознаватель цепочки Бэкуса-Наура.

На вход "проблемной" функции поступает string-овый двумерный массив, в первом столбце идет лексема, во втором класс лексемы.
[image]
По логике кода, если при проходе по массиву встречается ERROR, то делается проверка на принадлежность к ID или NUMBER, но цикл просто не запускается.

Прикладываю весь проект, код читаем и закомментирован.
http://rghost.ru/6m8cXGdT9

https://ideone.com/68e9e5

```
if (L[i, 2]) = 'ERROR' then  
begin
  Result[i, 1] := L[i, 1];
  if CheckID(L[i, 1]) then Result[i, 2] := 'ID' else // Проверка на принадлежность к ID
  if CheckNumber(L[i, 1]) then Result[i, 2] := 'NUMBER' else // Проверка на принадлежность к числу
  begin
    Result[i, 2] := 'SemanticERROR'; // Иначе ошибка
    N := 0;
    Exit;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Эээ... А вы не пробовали пройтись под отладчиком?

Comment: @VladD Да, конечно. Он показывает, что программа просто не заходит в этот цикл.

Comment: А в какой именно цикл? У вас snippet (`if (L[i, 2]) = 'ERROR' then`) вовсе не содержит циклов.

Comment: Я опечатался, вернее не цикл, а кусок кода, следующий за then. Виноват, голова закипает, целый день борюсь с этой проблемой.

Comment: Окей, не заходит. А чему равно `i` и `L[i, 2]` в этой точке?

Comment: Я починил. Надо было написать сравнивать не L массив, а Result массив. Вы подтолкнули меня в правильном направлении.

Comment: Вот, видите! Главное — задавать _себе_ вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

По коду могу сказать 2 вещи:

1. число N

   ```
   if N = 0 then Exit; // В случае ошибки выходим из функции
   assign(t, 'Hash4Lexems.txt');
   for i := 1 to N do
   ```

Вы проверили на возможность **`N < 0`** ? 
тут тоже цикл не будет работать

2. проверка числа

   ```
   function IsNum(c: char): Boolean;
   begin
     Result := True;
     if (c > '9') or (c < '1') then
       Result := False;    
   end;
   ```

тут почему `(c < '1')` а не `(c < '0')`

Comment: 1. Если бы N было = 0, то сразу был бы выход из программы и if, then и прочим зарезервированным словам не назначались классы.  
    
  2. Это да, спасибо большое, исправлю.